# How can I retrieve error strings for DirectX 9

Tags: c++, winapi, com, error-handling, directx

I want to retrieve error strings for DirectX 9, but I can find on the web is using the FormatMessage() and _com_error.ErrorMessage(), both of which fail me.

```
hr = g_pd3dDevice->GetRenderTargetData(...
... // the debugger tells me hr = 0x8876086c
FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
    NULL, hr, 0, (LPTSTR)&lpBuf, 0, NULL))
// it returns 0 with lpBuf unallocated
```

FormatMessage() fails and I use the it again with GetLastError() to see why FormatMessage() fails:
"The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2."

_com_error.ErrorMessage() tells me "Unknown error 0x8876086c"

Comment: BTW: is there a common way to get error strings for all HRESULT?

Comment: Not really, error codes and messages are categorized. For example, network subsystem has its own codes and messages, DX has its own, etc. So you must know a type of operation you were performing in order to get a message corresponding to the error you are getting.

Comment: Look at the d3d9.h header file for error codes.  You'll find a match with D3DERR_INVALIDCALL, the string isn't going to tell you why you passed invalid arguments.  Nor does your snippet.

Comment: As you mentioned network APIs, I used GetLastError() with FormatMessage for winsock APIs and it works though MSDN says to use WSAGetLastError() instead. I don't know if it is a reliable way.

Comment: @Hans Passant you are right. But I am looking for a way to display the error for all DX9 APIs that I use, not just this single case.

Comment: @LeOpArD: Have a look here - http://alax.info/blog/1383 the tool covers a few thousand of `HRESULT` codes from different APIs and decodes the values in a convenient way.

Comment: @RomanR. Really nice tool. Thanks for recommending!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To get DirectX error message, there are two functions — `DXGetErrorString()` and `DXGetErrorDescription()`. That being said, `FormatMessage()` will not get you what you want. Here is a small example:

```
// You'll need this include file and library linked.
#include <DxErr.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "dxerr.lib")
```

...

```
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s error description: %s\n",
        DXGetErrorString(hr), DXGetErrorDescription(hr));
}
```

Comment: dxerr is deprecated. Moreover according to below link - "The VS 2015 C Runtime is not compatible with the DXERR.LIB that ships in the legacy DirectX SDK"  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/04/24/wheres-dxerr-lib/

Comment: The page in the comment above has moved to https://walbourn.github.io/wheres-dxerr-lib/

Answer (score 1):

According to https://walbourn.github.io/wheres-dxerr-lib/ (also linked to by kreuzerkrieg's comment):

> HRESULTS for DirectX graphics APIs were added to the FormatMessage
>   function when using FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM in Windows 8 which
>   already supports most of the system error codes reported by DXERR

At the same time, the previous DXERR.LIB library containing the `DXGetErrorString()` function was removed in Windows SDK 8 (into which the DirectX SDK was merged).

If you want a solution that works on any Windows OS, you can use the "streamlined version" of the DXERR.LIB library, MIT licensed, posted on that website.